# Laravel Eloquent model overriding static boot method

Tags: php, laravel

I want to override model events and found this example code but am not sure I understand it completely.

SOURCE:

http://driesvints.com/blog/using-laravel-4-model-events/

There is a static method with another static method in it...How does that work? Or is it setting a static property in the boot method somehow?

```
<?php

class Menu extends Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = array('name', 'time_active_start', 'time_active_end', 'active');

    public $timestamps = false;

    public static $rules = array(
        'name' => 'required',
        'time_active_start' => 'required',
        'time_active_end' => 'required'
    );

   public static function boot()
   {
       parent::boot();

       static::saving(function($post)
       {

       });       
   }    

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`static::saving()` just calls the static method `saving` on itself (and parent classes if not existent in current class). So it is essentially doing the same as:

```
Menu::saving(function($post){

});
```

So it is registering a callback for the `saving` event within the boot function.

[Laravel documentation on model events](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#model-events)

Comment: Since I am calling the saving method from the boot method how does laravel know when to give me a call back?

Comment: What do you mean? That has nothing to do with the boot method. That's just how (model) events work. Before actually saving the model, Laravel will check for registered bindings and call them.